# How to compare patterns from lines within the same file with awk

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk

First of all, I just started learning `awk` and I'd like to challenge myself to pull this off in `bash`, so I'm not looking for the whole answer just some hints here and there, the way to do it, not the solution.

I basically get a big log file like this and I have to sort it out as follows:

- user logged in, user changed password, user logged off within same second (all 3 actions have to be done within 1 second);
- those actions (log in, change password, log off) happened one after another with no other entire in between.

So my output will need to be like this, only the profile names of the users that match the tests above.

```
fxsciaqulmlk
erdsfsdfsdf
fxsciaqulmla
```

Here I have a portion of the log file

```
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:39 +0200|178.57.66.225|fxsciaqulmlk| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:39 +0200|178.57.66.225|fxsciaqulmlk| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:39 +0200|178.57.66.225|fxsciaqulmlk| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:42 +0200|178.57.66.225|faaaaaa11111| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:40 +0200|178.57.66.215|terdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:49 +0200|178.57.66.215|terdsfsdfsdf| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:49 +0200|178.57.66.215|terdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:17:50 +0200|178.57.66.205|abcbbabab| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:17:50 +0200|178.57.66.205|abcbbabab| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:17:50 +0200|178.57.66.205|abcbbabab| - |user changed profile| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:17:50 +0200|178.57.66.205|abcbbabab| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|fxsciaqulmla| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|fxsciaqulmla| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|fxsciaqulmla| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:20:42 +0200|178.57.67.225|faaaa0a11111| - |user logged in| -
```

Here is were I got stuck.

```
#!/bin/bash

LIMIT="3"
LOG_FILE="${1}"


if [[ ! -e "${LOG_FILE}" ]]; then
  echo "Cannot open log file: ${LOG_FILE}" >&2
  exit 1
else
  grep 'changed password' -B1 -A1 ${LOG_FILE} \
  | awk '{print $5"\t"$6"\t"$9" "$10}' \
  | awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"; OFS="\t"} {print $1,$3,$4}' \
  | cut -d "    " -f1,3,4,5

....

fi
```

My logic is as follows: I'd like to check if the "changed password" string is on the line right after the "logged in" and before the "logged out" - if these are a match then I will want to compare if the actions were done within the same seconds.

Please let me know if my logic is good and what within `awk` I would need to use to get this done. I want to learn along the way, so if you can explain something, it's very much appreciated it.

Comment: You don't print milliseconds, so in case of 1 second difference, do you discard user?

Comment: 1) `grep -B1 -A1` can be combined into `grep -C1` 2) piping `grep` to `awk` to `awk` can usually be combined in a single `awk` 3) I would suggest write an **single** awk that fetch `changed password`, then a single `awk` that match changed password, logged in, logged off.

Comment: Why your output does not include `fxsciaqulmla` from `13:19:19 `? (also `erdsfsdfsdf`)

Comment: What if the 3 lines of a user are mixed on the same second with the 3 lines of another user? Can you be sure that your program will not log them mixed?

Comment: @thanasisp my output was just to show what I need, I know it's not complete.

Comment: @Archemar thank you! Indeed you're right.

Comment: @thanasisp, if the actions are messed up meaning not in order, and also if there's a second difference in between the actions - the user is discarded.

Comment: @robinhood If you know it's not complete, then please spend some time to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @thanasisp I have edited the post accordingly. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: The way I'd approach this is to use a State Machine. When we see the first line set the State to Seen1. When we see the second line and State is Seen1 then set it to Seen2. When we see the third line and we have State2 then we've got a match. If none of those are applicable then reset the State to Unseen.

Answer (score 4):

You can maintain a 3-line window over the file and whenever the last pattern is found, test against the current and last 2 lines.

```
BEGIN {
    FS = "|"
    text[2] = "user logged in"
    text[1] = "user changed password"
    text[0] = "user logged off"
}
    
$5 == text[0] && action[1] == text[1] && action[2] == text[2] &&
$3 == user[1] && $1 == time[1] && $3 == user[2] && $1 == time[2] {
    print $3
}
    
{
    time[2] = time[1]; user[2] = user[1]; action[2] = action[1]
    time[1] = $1; user[1] = $3; action[1] = $5
}
```

Usage:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
fxsciaqulmlk
erdsfsdfsdf
fxsciaqulmla
```

- The `BEGIN` group runs before parsing the first row, `FS` is the field separator.
- The second group has the condition to match to print a user. It is like spaghetti but effective. Order matters, as `awk` will stop evaluating every part at the first false found. So we put first the test for if the line refers a "log off", then if previous 2 lines the other actions.
- The last group is used to keep a window of 3 lines. Variables with hash `[1]` refer to the last line, and with `[2]` to the second to last.
- Notes: any variable not initialised is treated as an empty string (or the number zero, types are loose). Also, `awk` arrays are associative arrays, `1` and `2` are hashes here.

---

For the case you would like different/more tests on the previous rows, the skeleton is like this:

```
condition_for_last_row {
    for (i=1;i<=2;i++) {
        n = split(prev[i],arr)
        # do comparisons here, arr[1] to arr[n] are
        # the fields of the i-th previous row
    }
}

{
    prev[2] = prev[1]
    prev[1] = $0
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! I appreciate it! Let me put it together and get this done! But it will take me some time to learn how this all works. This is some advanced `awk` you threw at me!

Comment: I will add some notes/explanation here later.

Comment: or just point me to a good tutorial/manual where I can learn this from? I'd really love to master `awk`

Comment: @robinhood get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 2):

Using perl instead of awk, mainly for the convenience of the Date::Parse module's `str2time()` function:

```
$ perl -MDate::Parse -F'\|' -lane '
  if    (/user logged in/)        { $event{$F[2]}{login}  = str2time($F[0]) }

  elsif (/user changed password/) { $event{$F[2]}{passwd} = str2time($F[0]) }

  elsif (/user logged off/ &&
         defined($event{$F[2]}{login})  && 
         defined($event{$F[2]}{passwd}) &&
         (str2time($F[0]) - $event{$F[2]}{login} <= 1)) { print $F[2]; delete $event{$F[2]} }

  else { delete $event{$F[2]} }' input.log 
fxsciaqulmlk
erdsfsdfsdf
fxsciaqulmla
```

This perl one-liner uses the [Date::Parse](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Parse) module from the [TimeDate](https://metacpan.org/release/TimeDate) collection to convert the date field into a time_t value (seconds since the epoch, Midnight on Jan 1 1970).

The `-n` option tells perl to loop over its input without printing every line (similar to `sed`'s `-n` option), and each input line is auto-split into array `@F` (by the `-a` and `-F'\|'` options, which cause perl to behave similarly to how awk auto-splits each input line into $1, $2, $3, etc).  The `-l` option tells perl to automatically handle newlines at end-of-lines for both input and output.

The script keeps track of users who login and change their password, and the times that those events occur in a Hash (associative array) called `%events`.  %events is actually a Hash-of-Hashes (HoH, detailed in the Perl Data Structures Cookbook. see `man perldsc`), where each element (with the usernames as the key) is another hash (with either `login` or `passwd` as the keys, and the timestamp as the value).

If it sees both events for a particular user and then sees the same user logging out within 1 second of logging in, it prints the username and discards the events for that username.

If it sees any other event related to that user, it discards any current event records for that user.

It is written as a one-liner but could easily be converted to a stand-alone script.

NOTE: like arrays in bash and many other languages, perl arrays start from 0, not 1...so `$F[0]` is the first field (date & time), and `$F[2]` is the third field (username).