# Rewriting log parsing script in Perl or Python (get rid of awk)

Tags: awk, python, perl, python3

I need accomplish a task of filtering activity of bots in the log file.

Solution should only show  records meeting following criteria

- user logged in, user changed password, user logged off within same second.
- those actions (log in, change password, log off) happened one after another with no other entries in between.

Input data example

```
[a lot of data]
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:39 +0200|178.57.66.225|fxsciaqulmlk| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:39 +0200|178.57.66.225|fxsciaqulmlk| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:39 +0200|178.57.66.225|fxsciaqulmlk| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:42 +0200|178.57.66.225|faaaaaa11111| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:40 +0200|178.57.66.215|terdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:49 +0200|178.57.66.215|terdsfsdfsdf| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:49 +0200|178.57.66.215|terdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:17:50 +0200|178.57.66.205|abcbbabab| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:17:50 +0200|178.57.66.205|abcbbabab| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:17:50 +0200|178.57.66.205|abcbbabab| - |user changed profile| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:17:50 +0200|178.57.66.205|abcbbabab| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|fxsciaqulmla| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|fxsciaqulmla| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|fxsciaqulmla| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:20:42 +0200|178.57.67.225|faaaa0a11111| - |user logged in| -
[a lot of data]
```

I've written the code below in order to complete the task

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=" " } { c[$5]++; l[$5,c[$5]]=$0 } END { for (i in c) { if (c[i] == 3) for (j = 1 ; j <= c[i]; j++) print l[i,j] } }' $1
```

**Usage:**

*./parse_log.sh logfile.log*

**Output:**

```
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:39 +0200|178.57.66.225|fxsciaqulmlk| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:39 +0200|178.57.66.225|fxsciaqulmlk| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:39 +0200|178.57.66.225|fxsciaqulmlk| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|fxsciaqulmla| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|fxsciaqulmla| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|fxsciaqulmla| - |user logged off| -
```

But I want to know what alternative written in Perl or Python (with minimum usage of external libs)  would look?

Comment: You seem to have re-posted your older question (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/705788/rewriting-log-parsing-script-more-readable-and-if-possible-awk-free-way) that was closed as a duplicate of [How to compare patterns from lines within the same file with awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/705418)

Comment: @Kusalananda, that duplicate doesn't help me because of it produces cutted output from that I asking here. That means I need **all**  and uncutted lines from sequence `logged in|changed password|logged of` not only the 3 bot's name that pass the stages.

Comment: The reason that both your `awk` and your `python` scripts are not working is that you don't actually test the existence of `user logged in`, `user changed password` and `user logged off`. So if you test your Python code using as input 3 identical lines containing `user did something`, it will not discard these lines.

Comment: @thanasisp, Sure! But according to starting conditions we are guaranteed have all 3 actions within the same time interval.

Comment: If it is guaranteed that you will always have 3 actions within a second, then what's the reason to write a script to check if you have 3 actions within a second? You could just use `cat logfile.log`.

Comment: @thanasisp some other action from different bot on the same time or different actions' sequence.

Comment: The output in [the currently accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/705869/133219) doesn't match the desired output in the question nor does it match the output from the python script in [the OPs own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/705843/133219) so it's unclear what this question is really about.

Comment: @EdMorton, if you are talking about 
`Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged in| -
 Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged in| -`
duplication in my output and absence of such duplication in accepted answer I'd to inform you that such duplication acceptable. So, your downvote is a bit unfair to be honest, but it doesn't matter much as soon as I got all solutions I want to.

Comment: I'm talking about the accepted answer having no output for user `abcbbabab` when the expected output has lines for that user and your answer at the time I posted my comment having an output line `Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:17:50 +0200|178.57.66.205|abcbbabab| - |user changed profile| -` when the expected output doesn't have that line. If there's also some absent/missing duplication in some outputs you should address that in your question. A downvote for this nebulous question is very well-deserved but I'm glad you're getting answers to whatever it is you're asking about.

Comment: @EdMorton, I got your point.

I've put input and output data into a single view now.

Comment: I'm not sure you do get my point. The expected output shown in the question contains lines for user `abcbbabab` while the output shown in the accepted answer does not so how can it be the accepted answer if it doesn't produce the expected output? It's not clear if you're trying to get equivalent python/perl code for the shell script you posted or if you're trying to solve a problem in python/perl that the shell script you posted doesn't solve (in which case how is this different from your previous questions?) or something else.

Comment: @EdMorton,

Ah,  I realized finally, thanks!

Excuse me, please.
 
I was inattentive.

I'm trying to get equivalent and already got it.

Have a good weekend!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137024/discussion-between-twissell-and-ed-morton).

Comment: The log isnt date-hour sorted ? If yes why `Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:42 +0200|178.57.66.225|faaaaaa11111| - |user logged in| -` appears before `Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:40 +0200|178.57.66.215|terdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged in| -` ? Is it a typo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution itself is written in Python 3.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import re
from collections import defaultdict


column_delimiter = sys.argv[1]
column = int(sys.argv[2]) - 1

records = defaultdict(list)

with open(sys.argv[3]) as inputfile:
  for lines in inputfile:
    line = lines.rstrip('\n')
    row_record = line.split(column_delimiter)
    records[row_record[column]].append(line)

for timestamps in records.values():
    if len(timestamps) == 3:
        for i in range(len(timestamps)):
          if (re.search('logged in|changed password|logged off', timestamps[i])):
                  print(timestamps[i])
```

*Usage: `parse_log.py ' ' 5 logfile.log`*

The Python code is much easier to read and understand what it does.

Comment: Nice! From someone sometimes reviewing Python code contributions, a tiny feedback: `f`, `l`, `ll` and `r` aren't great names for variables! You can make your code even more readable by using good, descriptive names like `inputfile`, `line`, `timestamps` and `row_record`, for example :)

Comment: So: a well-earned upvote. Note that my signal-processing point of "nitpick" view from the previous question still stands: Something that happens 900 milliseconds after 12:00:00 and again 100 ms after 12:00:01 is only 200 ms (less than a second) apart, but gets two different timestamps, `12:00:00` and `12:00:01`. If you have truncated or rounded time values, you cannot with certainty detect events at the time quantization resolution! You will need to count all things that happen on the same or the following second,

Comment: and live with the fact that you're also catching things that happened between 1 and 2 seconds apart.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, thanks for notice about milliseconds, but I've no such time discreteness in start conditions of that task. Although you notice is worth to keep in mind

Comment: your timestamps are discretized to full seconds. You *have* that problem, whether you acknowledge it or not!

Comment: `Python code is much more easier to read and understand what it does.` is very much a matter of opinion (I personally can't tell what that python script is doing while I do know what your awk script does) but the awk script in your question is poorly written, with redundant code, crammed onto 1 line, and using a bunch of cryptic single letter variable names so it'd be easy to write something easier to read and understand using any tool, including awk.

Comment: @DanieleGrassini, nice remark! 
I've made requested correction.
Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

This is not an answer, but it is too big for a comment and requires formatting, so to address your comment that "The Python code is much easier to read and to understand what it does.", FYI an AWK script with sensible variable names that does what I *think* [your Python script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/705843/133219) does would look a lot like your python script but briefer since, for manipulating text, awk already does for you all the common stuff you have to write code to do in python:

```
awk -v column=5 '
    { records[$column] = records[$column] $0 ORS }
    END {
        for ( timestamp in records ) {
            if ( gsub(ORS,"&",records[timestamp]) > 2 ) {
                printf "%s", records[timestamp]
            }
        }
    }
' logfile.log
```

but reading the whole file into memory before processing it is a very inefficient approach to this problem. You should just do the test and print every time the time changes:

```
awk -v column=5 '
    $column != prev {
        prt()
        records = ""
        prev = $column
    }
    { records = records $0 ORS }
    END { prt() }

    function prt() {
        if ( gsub(ORS,"&",records) > 2 ) {
            printf "%s", records
        }
    }
' logfile.log
```

Answer (score 3):

With any `awk`:

```c
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { FS = "[|]" }

prvHour == $1 && prvUsr == $3 {
    if ($(NF-1) == "user logged in"        || 
        $(NF-1) == "user changed password" || 
        $(NF-1) == "user logged off" )
         actions[++actionCnt] = $0
    else actionCnt = 0
}

prvHour != $1 && prvUsr != $3 {
    if (prvHour && actionCnt == 3)
        for (i = 1; i <= actionCnt ; i++)
            print actions[i]

    prvHour = $1; prvUsr = $3
    actionCnt = 0 ; actions[++actionCnt] = $0
}

END {
    if (actionCnt == 3)
        for (i = 1; i <= actionCnt; i++)
            print actions[i]
}
```

---

With `Perl` without using external libraries :

```bash
/bin/perl -e '
    while (1) {
        $uli = $uli // <>;
        $ucp = <> if $uli =~ /^([^|]*)[|][^|]*[|]([^|]*)[|] - [|]user logged in[|] -$/;
        last if tell() < 0 ; 
        if (!defined $ucp) { $uli = undef ; next; }
        $ulo = <> if $ucp =~ /^(\Q$1\E)[|][^|]*[|]($2)[|] - [|]user changed password[|] -$/;
        last if tell() < 0;
        if (!defined $ulo) { $uli = $ucp ; $ucp = undef ; next ; }
        if ($ulo !~ /^\Q$1\E[|][^|]*[|]$2[|] - [|]user logged off[|] -$/) {
            $uli = $ulo ; $ucp = $ulo = undef ; next ;
        }
        print "$uli$ucp$ulo";
        $uli = $ucp = $ulo = undef;
    }
' sample
```

---

With `python3` usgin just `sys` to read the file and call `exit` with meaning values.

```py
#!/bin/python3
import sys

try:
    fullLine = actions = []
    prvHour = prvUsr = None
    chk_act = lambda x: x == "user logged in" or \
                 x == "user changed password" or \
                 x == "user logged off"


    with open(sys.argv[1]) as logFile:
        for line in logFile:
            hour, _, user, _, action, _ = line.split('|')
            if prvHour == hour and prvUsr == user:
                fullLine.append(line.strip())
                actions.append(action.strip())

            elif prvUsr != user and prvHour != hour:
                if len(actions) == 3 and all(map(chk_act, actions)):
                    print("\n".join(fullLine))

                prvUsr = user
                prvHour = hour
                actions = []
                actions.append(action.strip())
                fullLine = []
                fullLine.append(line.strip())


except IndexError:
    print("usage {} logfile".format(sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit(1)

except (FileNotFoundError, PermissionError):
    print("{} not found or permission permission denied", sys.argv[1])
    sys.exit(1)
```

---

With any `sed`:

```
#!/bin/sed -nf
N;/^\([^|]*\)|[^|]*|\([^|]*\)| - |user logged in| -\n\1|[^|]*|\2| - |user changed password| -$/{
    N;/\n\([^|]*\)|[^|]*|\([^|]*\)| - |user changed password| -\n\1|[^|]*|\2| - |user logged off| -$/{
        p;b
    }
    s/.*\n/\n/g;D
}
D
```

---

All solutions avoid to store the whole data in memory

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Perl solution:

```
 1  #!/usr/bin/env perl
 2  use strict;
 3  use warnings;
 4  my ($p2, $p1, $x);
 5  while (<>) {
 6      print($p2, $p1, $_) if
 7          /(.+)user logged off/
 8          && do { $x = $1 }
 9          && $p1 =~ /\Q$x\Euser changed password/
10          && $p2 =~ /\Q$x\Euser logged in/;
11      $p2 = $p1;
12      $p1 = $_;
13  }
```

Line 1 lets the shell know this is a Perl script [1].

Line 2 "The strict pragma disables certain Perl expressions that could behave unexpectedly or are difficult to debug, turning them into errors. " [2]

Line 3 "The warnings pragma gives control over which warnings are enabled in which parts of a Perl program." [3]

Line 4 declares local variables [4, 5]:

- `$p2` is the second previous line of input.
- `$p1` is the previous line of input.
- `$x` is for saving the initial portion of the current line of input.

Lines 5-13 form a `while` compound statement [6].

Line 5 the `while` loop expression uses the null filehandle `<>` (diamond operator) [7], allowing the solution to be used as a Unix filter [8]. For each line of input, `while` will assign the current line of input to the default input general variable `$_` [9] and evaluate `BLOCK`.

Lines 6-10 form an `if` compound statement using statement modifier syntax [10].

Lines 7-10 form the `EXPR` portion of the `if` statement, which is composed of three regular expressions [11], one `do BLOCK` function [12], and the C-style logical "and" operator `&&` [13].

Line 7 attempts to match the current line of input against the regular expression `/(.+)user logged off/`.  If successful, the initial portion of the current line of input is captured into the global variable `$1` [15].

If line 7 was true, line 8 saves `$1` to the local variable `$x`.   (Subsequent regular expressions may clobber the value of `$1`.) The `do BLOCK` evaluates to the the value of the last statement of `BLOCK`, which will be a non-empty string, which Perl considers true.

If line 8 was true, line 9 attempts to match the previous line of input against the regular expression `/\Q$x\Euser changed password/`.  `$x` must be escaped within the regular expression using the delimiters `\Q` and `\E`, so that its value is treated as a string.

If line 9 was true, line 10 attempts to match the second previous line of input using the regular expression `/\Q$x\Euser logged in/`.

If line 10 is true, line 6 prints the second previous line of input, the previous line of input, and the current line of input.

Lines 11-12 update the variables for second previous line of input and previous line of input.

The solution produces output in the same order as the input:

```
$ perl solution.pl logfile.log
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:39 +0200|178.57.66.225|fxsciaqulmlk| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:39 +0200|178.57.66.225|fxsciaqulmlk| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:39 +0200|178.57.66.225|fxsciaqulmlk| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|fxsciaqulmla| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|fxsciaqulmla| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|fxsciaqulmla| - |user logged off| -
```

References:

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

[2] https://perldoc.perl.org/strict

[3] https://perldoc.perl.org/warnings

[4] https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata

[5] https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my

[6] https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Compound-Statements

[7] https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#I%2FO-Operators

[8] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(software)#Unix

[9] https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#General-Variables

[10] https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Statement-Modifiers

[12] https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre

[13] https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do

[14] https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#C-style-Logical-And

[15] https://perldoc.perl.org/variables/$%3Cdigits%3E%20($1,%20$2,%20...)

Comment: >>The problem statement requirements "within same second" and "1 second" are in conflict.

    Fixed. Thanks for remark.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Perl this can be written as a one-liner, but it feels a bit cluttered:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -F'\|' -ae '$epoch=Time::Piece->strptime($F[0], "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")->epoch; $diff=$epochlast2 - $epoch; $last =~ /user changed password/ && $last2 =~ /user logged in/ && $_ =~ /user logged off/ && $diff==0 && print $last2, $last, $_; $epochlast2=$epochlast; $epochlast=$epoch; $last2=$last; $last=$_' <<< "$data"
```

```
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:39 +0200|178.57.66.225|fxsciaqulmlk| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:39 +0200|178.57.66.225|fxsciaqulmlk| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:39 +0200|178.57.66.225|fxsciaqulmlk| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|fxsciaqulmla| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|fxsciaqulmla| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|fxsciaqulmla| - |user logged off| -
```

alternatively, as a script:

```
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

my $epochlast2=0;
my $epochlast=0;
my $last2="";
my $last="";

while($line = <STDIN>){
    $date=(split(/\|/, $line))[0];
    $epoch=Time::Piece->strptime($date, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")->epoch; 
    $diff=$epochlast2 - $epoch;
    if ($last =~ /user changed password/ && $last2 =~ /user logged in/ && $line =~ /user logged off/ && $diff==0) {
        print $last2, $last, $line; 
    }
    $epochlast2=$epochlast; 
    $epochlast=$epoch; 
    $last2=$last; 
    $last=$line
}
```

Comment: Could you give me a favor and provide Python solution as well?
Your solution is one of the best here, thus it accepted. I like your approach very much.

Comment: @Twissell you asked for a solution in Perl. Here is one. Why should the OP spend their time _for free_ rewriting it in a different language?

Comment: @roaima, your point sounds reasonable, but I asked OP if he be so kind to provide another example and have spare time to write it. 
I've asked not mandating it, just FYI.

Comment: Regarding `In Perl this can be written as a one-liner, but it feels a bit cluttered` - in most tools it can be written as a one-liner (and feel cluttered).

Comment: @Twissell I added another answer in response to your request. I don't really mind to write the pythonic version of this, but given some code in one language, you should be able to write the equivalent code in another language rather easily (and https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a great resource to get feedback)

Comment: @EdMorton Technically yes, but I was referring to the fact that Perl is well-known for its expressiveness which allows you to write concise one-liners easily. However, this is not a great example of that.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have the python version of my previous script (reading from stdin)

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime

last2 = ""
last = ""
datelast2 = None
datelast = None

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.rstrip()
    elems = line.split("|")
    date = datetime.strptime(elems[0], "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
    if datelast2 is not None:
        diff = datelast2 - date
    if (
        "user changed password" in last
        and "user logged in" in last2
        and "user logged off" in line
        and diff.seconds == 0
    ):
        print("{}\n{}\n{}".format(last2, last, line))
    last2 = last
    last = line
    datelast2 = datelast
    datelast = date
```

Comment: Take in a consideration that both versions of script you've provided skip bot named `abcbbabab`. It may happen because of shorter bot's name... I don't know exactly the case of such behaviour.

Comment: Yes, that's because for that bot, there is an additional action `user changed profile` that doesn't follow your second criterion.

Comment: seems you are right!
That means  both my approaches are wrong and method with extracting strings with identical timestamps and then filtering by action doesn't work. That's worth considering when thinking.

Comment: The timestamp conditional seems to hold at least based on the input data. Maybe you just need to tweak the rest of the conditions to include such edge cases.

Comment: Done. The OP and my own answer have been updated.

Answer (score 2):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -MDateTime::Parse -e 'my @a; my @b; for lines() {   \
         @a.push($_.split(/ "|" | \s "-" \s? /, :skip-empty));  \
         @b.push(DateTime::Parse.new(@a.[*-1][0]).posix)}; my %c.=append([Z=>] @b, @a>>.[1..*-1]);  \
         for %c.sort -> $i {$i.raku.put if $i.values.contains("user logged in" & "user changed password" & "user logged off")  \
         && ($i.value.elems == 9)}'  file
```

Sample Output:

```
"1471864539" => $["178.57.66.225", "fxsciaqulmlk", "user logged in", "178.57.66.225", "fxsciaqulmlk", "user changed password", "178.57.66.225", "fxsciaqulmlk", "user logged off"]
"1471864559" => $["178.57.66.205", "erdsfsdfsdf", "user logged in", "178.57.66.205", "erdsfsdfsdf", "user changed password", "178.57.66.205", "erdsfsdfsdf", "user logged off"]
"1471864759" => $["178.56.66.225", "fxsciaqulmla", "user logged in", "178.56.66.225", "fxsciaqulmla", "user changed password", "178.56.66.225", "fxsciaqulmla", "user logged off"]
```

If you're looking for a scripting language to use at the command line, you might want to consider Raku. The code is relatively short, and includes a few niceties--including taking advantage of Raku's built-in hashing capabilities.

Reading the code above, `lines` are read-in and each line is `split` on `|` pipes and/or `\s "-" \s?`  whitespace-dash. This returns four elements per line (zero-index = 0..3). Each line is `push`ed onto the `@a` array. Then the first column of each line is parsed using `DateTime::Parse.new()` to return `posix` seconds, which is pushed onto the `@b` array.

From these two arrays a hash `%c` is created using Raku's `[Z=>]` Zip-reduction metaoperator. This gives a `%c` hash with posix seconds as `key`, and zero-indexed columns 1,2,3 as `value`. As the elements are `append`ed to the `%c` hash, their values append to the appropriate `posix` key. Finally in the out`put`, for each posix-key element, values are checked to make sure they `contain` the exact three strings requested, and also checked that exactly 9 elements exist (three rows of three columns).

---

Sample Input:

```
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:39 +0200|178.57.66.225|fxsciaqulmlk| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:39 +0200|178.57.66.225|fxsciaqulmlk| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:39 +0200|178.57.66.225|fxsciaqulmlk| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:42 +0200|178.57.66.225|faaaaaa11111| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:40 +0200|178.57.66.215|terdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:49 +0200|178.57.66.215|terdsfsdfsdf| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:49 +0200|178.57.66.215|terdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:17:50 +0200|178.57.66.205|abcbbabab| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:17:50 +0200|178.57.66.205|abcbbabab| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:17:50 +0200|178.57.66.205|abcbbabab| - |user changed profile| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:17:50 +0200|178.57.66.205|abcbbabab| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|fxsciaqulmla| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|fxsciaqulmla| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|fxsciaqulmla| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:20:42 +0200|178.57.67.225|faaaa0a11111| - |user logged in| -
```

*[Thanks to @bduggan and @sergot for updating Raku's `DateTime::Parse` module so quickly!]*

https://andrewshitov.com/2020/06/06/some-tips-for-working-with-hashes-in-raku/
https://github.com/sergot/datetime-parse
https://raku.org

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
timesecond=[]
fil=open('/home/praveen/file.txt','r')
for i in fil:
    if i.strip().split(' ')[4] not in timesecond:
        timesecond.append(i.strip().split(' ')[4])


fincheck=open('/home/praveen/file.txt','r')
fincheck_final=fincheck.readlines()

finalcapt=[]
for test2 in timesecond:
    for test3 in range(0,len(fincheck_final),1):
        if test2.strip() in fincheck_final[test3].strip().split(' ')[4]:
            bj="{0} {1}".format(test3,test2)
            finalcapt.append(bj)
            break


for bgy in finalcapt:
    bgy_fin=bgy.strip().split(' ')
    wordcheck=bgy_fin[1]
    exsichec=int(bgy_fin[0])
#    print fincheck_final[exsichec].strip().split(' ')
    try:
        if wordcheck in fincheck_final[exsichec] and wordcheck in fincheck_final[exsichec].strip().split(' ')[4] and "user logged in" in fincheck_final[exsichec]:
            if wordcheck in fincheck_final[exsichec+1] and wordcheck in fincheck_final[exsichec+1].strip().split(' ')[4] and "user changed password" in fincheck_final[exsichec+1]:
                if wordcheck in fincheck_final[exsichec+2] and wordcheck in fincheck_final[exsichec+2].strip().split(' ')[4] and "user logged off" in fincheck_final[exsichec+2]:
    
                    print fincheck_final[exsichec],fincheck_final[exsichec+1],fincheck_final[exsichec+2]
     
    except:
        pass
```

output

```
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:39 +0200|178.57.66.225|fxsciaqulmlk| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:39 +0200|178.57.66.225|fxsciaqulmlk| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:39 +0200|178.57.66.225|fxsciaqulmlk| - |user logged off| -

Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:15:59 +0200|178.57.66.205|erdsfsdfsdf| - |user logged off| -

Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|fxsciaqulmla| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|fxsciaqulmla| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|fxsciaqulmla| - |user logged off|
```